# Flutter - ordering Widget class members

Tags: flutter, code-organization

In the [following section](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Style-guide-for-Flutter-repo#order-other-class-members-in-a-way-that-makes-sense) of the Flutter style guide it suggests to put the widget's `build` method after all other methods, even the private ones that the `build` method uses. In theory it collides with a general rule of putting private class members after public class members. While developing real Flutter apps I've also noticed that if I want to fully understand a widget's private method, I usually need to start from going to a place where it's called.

What's a reason for putting `build` method after private methods that it uses?